# ORA-01749 - Oracle 12c vs 11g

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

There is some difference when I execute

```
create view XDUAL
as select * from dual

grant select on XDUAL to USER
```

between Oracle 12c and 11g (replace USER with your current user). It gives me an error only on 11g:

```
ORA-01749: you may not GRANT/REVOKE privileges to/from yourself
```

But it works fine on 12c. It's possible to GRANT privileges to myself on my own objects.

The definition of users are the same. They have exactly the same content of `USER_ROLE_PRIVS` and `USER_SYS_PRIVS.` 
Do you know what the reason is? Is it possible to disable somehow the error on 11g?

BTW. Do not point me that it doesn't make sense to give privileges to myself for my object. I know that and it's not a solution. I have some package that works fine on 12c and doesn't work on 11g and I cannot modify it for some reasons.

Comment: Is the package created the same way? Sounds like maybe one has definer rights and one has invoker rights. Or possibly in 12c you're calling the package as its owner, while in 11g you're calling it from a different account - though that could be through some intermediate package's invoker/definer rights. (Running what you've shown works for me in 11.2.0.4 though).

Comment: @AlexPoole 11.2.0.1 is mine. I will try to apply the patchset to see if it helps..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is related to Oracle version. 
The error is shown on 11.2.0.1  but after applying of 11.2.0.4 it does not exist.
The issue was changed/fixed by Oracle somewhere between these versions.

Comment: Possibly related to undocumented bug 8984274, which was patched in 11.2.0.2 (see MOS 1345539.1).